# Minifuse only taking Mono Input

Tags: audio-recording, audio-interfaces, audacity, mono

I have an Arturia MiniFuse 2 and a digital keyboard. I'm trying to record my keyboard into my MiniFuse which is relatively straightforward - quarter inch to quarter inch cable, from the stereo output from my keyboard into the first input on my Arturia. When I plug my MiniFuse into my computer to record, it only appears in the left channel for some reason, even though the output is stereo. Is there a way to fix this so that I can record my keyboard in stereo?

I'm recording into Audacity, but when I record directly into my DAW, the same issue occurs.

Comment: Can you clarify - stereo output of your keyboard… is this one stereo cable, TRS or two mono cables, TS? Your arturia cannot take stereo in a single socket [TRS] only to both inputs [TS x 2]. If you have one cable to it, you will get one channel.

Comment: Ah, it is one cable, but there is also only one stereo output on the cable? I'm not sure if it is stereo or not, how would I check? I think it is a guitar cable

Comment: You cannot send a stereo output to a mono input [well, it will fit but it won't work.] You need a Y-cable, TRS to 2x TS.

Comment: Good to know, thank you!